# Need help outputting the result once after comparing array with char array

Tags: c++

As the title says, I'm having a bit of problem where I want the output from the function to print out once, and not print it out each time it compares each array element.

```
void westeros::display(Kingdom total[], int count, char m_name[])
{
    cout << "Searching for kingdom Mordor in Westeros" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (total[i].m_name != m_name)
        {
            cout << m_name << " is not a part of Westeros" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mordor is part of Arda, not Westeros; shame on you. ^^

Comment: You could achieve the thing trivially with a simple flag. Furthermore, it only prints if the compared names do not match, not "each time"; I'm not sure what you actually want. Do you want to print one time if one or more mismatches have been detected?

Comment: I had to look up what `westeros` is. Shame on me.

Comment: Yes, so it would check the 5 cities I've entered, and once that is done. it should print that Mordor wasn't one of the cities that i've metioned, and should only print the message once. But in this program it's giving the message to each city that it's been compared too. ( I would like it for it to print only one time :) ),

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean and set it to true after printing.

```
void westeros::display(Kingdom total[], int count, char m_name[])
{
    cout << "Searching for kingdom Mordor in Westeros" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    bool hasPrinted = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (total[i].m_name != m_name && !hasPrinted)
        {
            cout << m_name << " is not a part of Westeros" << endl;
            hasPrinted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Printing conditionally *after* the loop would eliminate the need to check for `!hasPrinted` every time. It also expresses the intent better, IMO.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll keep this in mind!! When I do comparisons.

Comment: @VimalanKarunaFwuffeh What do you mean? It seems clear to me. First it is set to `false`, it checks if it is `false` before printing, and when it prints, it is set to `true` so the if statement will not run again.